# Quick one: Programmatic Animations with Windows Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is this really the proper and only way to programmatically set the target of an animation in a Windows Store app?

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, someElement);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");
```

It just seems odd not to use an instance method or property on either a Timeline or Storyboard.

It's the programming equivalent of reaching in your car window and using the interior handle to open the door.

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the correct way, yes. I do agree it could be made simpler, but it is how it has been since WPF.

Comment: Cheers Filip, just needed a sanity check. I ended-up writing a DependencyObject.BeginAnimation extension method to mimic WPFs.